OAuth error when accessing Meta Threads API
I do not know where the OAuth error comes from, when I use a wrong ID or access token i get a different error.
curl -i -X POST "https://graph.threads.net/v1.0/user_id_placeholder/threads" -d "media_type=IMAGE" -d "image_url=https://i.postimg.cc/7LLYvNSq/pexels-ozanculha-17858988.jpg" -d "text=#BronzFonz" -d "access_token=placeholder"

{"error":{"message":"An unexpected error has occurred. Please retry your request later.","type":"OAuthException","is_transient":true,"code":2,"fbtrace_id":"AuXxSa8ftZnjb-aSSAuGr_O"}}


I was using the wrong ID.
You get the correct ID here, https://graph.threads.net/me?access_token=USER_YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN
